# Disable updating data when database is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem when I want to echo "The stock is less than what  you want". The problem is the user still can update the cart when the stock in my database less that what the user wants. It should show an error "The stock is less than what you want".

This is my code.

```
<?php session_start();
require("config.php");

$user = $_SESSION['userlogin'];
$cek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transaksitbl WHERE username = '$user' AND status ='0'") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_num_rows($cek);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($cek);
if ($result > 0)
{
$faktur =$data['notransaksi'];
for ($i=1; $i<=$_POST['n']; $i++)
{
  $idp = $_POST['id'.$i];
  $cari2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM barangtbl WHERE id='$idp'") or die(mysql_error());      
  $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($cari2);
  $har = $row2['harga'];
  $stock = $row2['stock'];
  if($_POST['n'] <= $row2['stock'])
  {
    echo "The stock is less than what you want";
  }
  if ($cari2)
  {
    $jmlubah = $_POST['jumlah'.$i];
    $beratnew = $jmlubah*$row2['berat'];
    $totubah = $jmlubah*$har;

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE transaksirincitbl SET jumlah = $jmlubah, jumlah_berat = $beratnew, total_berat = $beratnew, subtotal=$totubah 
      WHERE id ='$idp' and username = '$user' And notransaksi =$faktur") or die(mysql_error());
  }
}
}
header ("location:shopping_cart.php");
?>
```

Comment: All manner of problems here: SQL injection, race conditions, no rollback, deprecated `mysql_*()` API. Where to start?

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, i still a newbie in php and study hard step by step for update the code. all i need first is complete the problem above. would you help me sir?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you properly the

```
if($cari2){}
```

function is executing?
All you are checking there is if the $cari2 variable is true.
Simply make a else statement out of the if($cari2){} statement so that if the stock is less than you wan't the second if statement won't get executed.

So, like this:

```
if($_POST['n'] <= $row2['stock']){
     echo "The stock is less than you want";
   }
else { 
      if($scari2){
         $jmlubah = $_POST['jumlah'.$i];
         $beratnew = $jmlubah*$row2['berat'];
         $totubah = $jmlubah*$har;

         $query = mysql_query("UPDATE transaksirincitbl SET jumlah = $jmlubah,      jumlah_berat = $beratnew, total_berat = $beratnew, subtotal=$totubah 
         WHERE id ='$idp' and username = '$user' And notransaksi =$faktur") or   die(mysql_error());

     } else {
        die('Woop, there seems to be a problem with the $scari2 variable. The value is:' . $scari2);
     } // END OF INNER ELSE
 } // END OF ELSE
```

And one more thing NEVER forget to use the  **mysql_real_escape_string()** function on a variable before submiting it's value to the database.

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, but when i try the code like you said above it still not work, not only it still not work but also the quantity that i want to update is not work too.

Comment: Well it is really hard to answer for me because i really dont understand what you are trying to acomplish. Did you paste my code where your if and else statement is? If you are trying to run just my code then it surely won't work.

Comment: maybe like this sir, the main point of my problem is user is not allowed to update their cart if the stock in database isnot enough.

Comment: I have just noticed that you redirect the client to the shopping cart without checking if there is enough stock in the database:

header ("location:shopping_cart.php");
Move this code into the code else statement that i wrote up there.